# Outlook 2016 Addin VSTO Catch new calendar event

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in

I have a Add-in for Outlook 2016 and I catch when a new calendar event is created by code:

```
inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
            inspectors.NewInspector +=
            new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);
```

This is working fine if the user:
1. Click on [New Appointment] in the ribbon
2. Right click on the calendar and choose [New Appointment]
3. Doubleclick in the calendar

But if the user create a new calendar event by entering a text directly in the calendar the event is not raised.

[image]

How do I catch this?

Answer (score 2):

In that case no Inspector window is created, so you will not trap into the NewInspector event. Instead, you can handle the [ItemAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx) event of the Items class which is fired when one or more items are added to the specified collection. Note, this event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once.